# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' not found in config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Trying to follow the book [Learning Rails 3](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/ruby/9781449332211) on a CentOS 6 Linux with rails 4 and ruby 2

[image: book picture]

And it repeatedly suggests me to uncomment a line in `config/routes.rb`:

*Once again, you’ll need to enable routing for your controller. You’ll need to edit the config/routes.rb file. Remove the # that has been bolded below:*

```
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
    end
```

but there is no such line in the [config/routes.rb](http://pastebin.com/7qtYwr1N) - at least not after I run something like

```
 # rails new guestbook
 # cd guestbook/
 # rails generate controller entries
 # vim app/controllers/entries_controller.rb
 # vim app/views/entries/sign_in.html.erb
 # rails server
```

Is there maybe a new similar configuration line in Rails 4?

Comment: if i am correct than match are removed in Rails 4

Comment: Removed - okay, but what to put into `routes.rb` instead - to get the `guestbook` working?

Comment: You have to put something in routs.rb. Try this `root 'entries#index'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of regular route:

```
get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

And root like this.

```
root 'home#index'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a catch-all route like this:

```
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```